# How follow a relationship backward from a M2O to O2O?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

The `UserProfile` has a one-to-one to 'User' and a many-to-one to `Place`

```
class UserProfile( models.Model ) :
    user  = models.OneToOneField( User )
    place = models.ForeignKey( Place, null = True, blank = True )
```

In my the detail view of `Place`, I want to list all the *residents* for that `Place`. In other words, I want to list all `User`s, whose `UserProfile` had the specified `Place`.

In my template, I tried

```
{% for resident in place.user_profile_set.user_set.all %}
```

But that didn't work. I guess I am missing something fundamentally in Django's concept of ["following a relationship backwards"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)?

Comment: Nice idea is to use [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Comment: It can be difficult to anylize your queries (running time) if you have a large project with many templates and .py source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing two things, yes.

The first is that the backwards relation from `Place` to `UserProfile` is `userprofile_set`, not `user_profile_set`.

The second is that from there to `User` is not a backwards relation at all: it is forwards, because the FK is defined on the `UserProfile` model. So from `UserProfile` to `User`, you just do `.user` - and it's a single element, not a queryset.

So, as pastylegs says, you iterate through the profiles in `place.userprofile_set.all` and do `profile.user`.

Comment: Duh, right. `UserProfile` to `User` is forward haha. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 3):

What about something like the following:

```
{% for resident in place.userprofile_set.all %}
    {{ resident.user }}
{% endfor %}
```